# Canvas fallback to flash is loading images

Tags: javascript, html, flash, canvas

In my site I show ads with flash

I still use flash  because my visitors have older browsers that not support html5

If the user has no flash support, I show a canvas ad

If the user has no flash support or has no canvas support, I show them a image

This is my code:

```
<p>
<object width="728" height="90" classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" id="alter-content" align="middle">
    <param value="http://www.bellezaculichi.com/banners/47.swf" name="movie">
    <param name="quality" value="high">
    <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff">
    <param name="play" value="true">
    <param name="loop" value="true">
    <param name="wmode" value="window">
    <param name="scale" value="showall">
    <param name="menu" value="false">
    <param name="devicefont" value="false">
    <param name="salign" value="">
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always">
    <!--[if !IE]>-->
    <object data="http://www.bellezaculichi.com/banners/47.swf" width="728" height="90" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
        <param name="movie" value="http://www.bellezaculichi.com/banners/47.swf">
        <param name="quality" value="high">
        <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff">
        <param name="play" value="true">
        <param name="loop" value="true">
        <param name="wmode" value="window">
        <param name="scale" value="showall">
        <param name="menu" value="false">
        <param name="devicefont" value="false">
        <param name="salign" value="">
        <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always">
        <!--<![endif]-->

        <!-- inicia sin flash -->
        <script>
            window.onload = function() {
                canvasApp();
            }

            function canvasApp() {

                var mi_canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

                if (!mi_canvas || !mi_canvas.getContext) {
                    return;
                }


                var context = mi_canvas.getContext("2d");

                var pic = new Image();

                pic.src = "./banners/" + 47 + ".jpg";

                pic.addEventListener('load', imagen_cargada, false);

                function imagen_cargada() {
                    dibuja_canvas();
                }


                function dibuja_canvas() {
                    context.drawImage(pic, 0, 0, 728, 90);
                }

                function onMouseClick(e)

                {

                    window.open("http://www.si-net.com.mx/registro.php", '_blank');
                }

                mi_canvas.addEventListener("click", onMouseClick, false);

                dibuja_canvas();

            }
        </script>

        <canvas id="canvas" width="728" height="90" style="cursor:pointer;">
            <!-- si no soporta canvas -->
            <a href="http://www.si-net.com.mx/registro.php" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">
                <img src="./banners/47.jpg" width="728" height="90" border="0">
            </a>
            <!-- si no soporta canvas -->
        </canvas>

        <!-- fin sin flash -->

        <!--[if !IE]>-->
    </object>
    <!--<![endif]-->
</object>
</p>
```

It works...

I use Google Chrome Developer Tools to test and I discover that people with flash, load the image used in the canvas fallback

It is not necessary to load  the image used in the canvas  if the user has flash...

How can I avoid  to load  the image used in the canvas  if the user has flash?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Usually what I see is a background image behind a flash. So if the user has flash, they will see the ad, if not, see the background (usually saying "please disable ad block" (also, that would be your main concern and there really is not a way to get around that.)

Answer (score 0):

I achieve what I wanted. I avoided loading canvas resources if the user has flash installed.

This is my code:

```
<object width="900" height="506" classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" id="alter-content" align="middle">
<param value="catarina.swf" name="movie" />
<param name="quality" value="high" />
<param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
<param name="play" value="true" />
<param name="loop" value="true" />
<param name="wmode" value="window" />
<param name="scale" value="showall" />
<param name="menu" value="false" />
<param name="devicefont" value="false" />
<param name="salign" value="" />
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
<!--[if !IE]>-->
<object data="catarina.swf" width="900" height="506" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
    <param name="movie" value="catarina.swf" />
    <param name="quality" value="high" />
    <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
    <param name="play" value="true" />
    <param name="loop" value="true" />
    <param name="wmode" value="window" />
    <param name="scale" value="showall" />
    <param name="menu" value="false" />
    <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
    <param name="salign" value="" />
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
    <!--<![endif]-->
    <!-- inicia sin flash -->
    <div id="swiffycontainer" style="width: 550px; height: 400px">
    </div>
    <script>
        var hasFlash = false;
        try {
            var fo = new ActiveXObject('ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash');
            if (fo) {
                hasFlash = true;
            }
        } catch (e) {
            if (navigator.mimeTypes && navigator.mimeTypes['application/x-shockwave-flash'] != undefined && navigator.mimeTypes['application/x-shockwave-flash'].enabledPlugin) {
                hasFlash = true;
            }
        }
        if (hasFlash == false) {


            function load_animacion() {

                var animacion = document.createElement("script");

                animacion.type = "text/javascript";

                animacion.src = "catarina-v02.js";

                document.head.appendChild(animacion);
            }

            function loadSwiffy() {


                var animacion_canvas = document.createElement("script");

                animacion_canvas.type = "text/javascript";

                animacion_canvas.src = "https://www.gstatic.com/swiffy/v7.2.0/runtime.js";

                if (animacion_canvas.readyState) {
                    animacion_canvas.onreadystatechange = function() {
                        if (animacion_canvas.readyState == "loaded" || animacion_canvas.readyState == "complete") {
                            animacion_canvas.onreadystatechange = null;

                            load_animacion();
                        }
                    };
                } else {
                    animacion_canvas.onload = function() {
                        load_animacion();
                    };
                }



                document.head.appendChild(animacion_canvas);

            }



            window.onload = loadSwiffy;
            // carga la libreria de swiffy


        }
    </script>

    <!-- fin sin flash -->

    <!--[if !IE]>-->
</object>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

If the user has no flash suport, it loads dynamically the javascript code necesary to create the CANVAS animation.

In this example firts loads SWIFFY library (https://www.gstatic.com/swiffy/v7.2.0/runtime.js)

When the library is loaded, then loads ths js code (catarina-v02.js)  to create and animate the canvas

This way I avoided loading canvas resources if the user has flash installed.